# Customize the z-index of the react material ui select backdrop

Tags: material-ui

I have a select component inside a popover. They both render backdrops with zindex: 1300 when opened. I also have a tag component that I want to show on top of the popover backdrop, however this causes it to be on top of the select backdrop as well.
I need to set the select backdrop to a higher number, is there a way to customize it?

I have tried to change the z-index of the select itself or use the id of the backdrop to change it however it has an inline style that overrides mine and I would rather have a better solution than use !important

this is the rendered backdrop

```
<div role="presentation" id="menu-label" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1300; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
```

I would like my tag to be on top of the popover backdrop but behind the select backdrop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the z-index of the opening items of  with MenuProps. Example:

```
 <Select
     MenuProps={{
         style: {zIndex: 35001}
     }}
 >
     {this.renderSelectItems()}
 </Select>`
```

This property doesn't seem to be documented (anymore?) but has been working for quite a while now.

Comment: i just tried using this property and it actually applied these styles to the parent "presentation" div of the menu select