# How do you set the z-index of a Backdrop in material-ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the Backdrop component in materialui, and having trouble setting the zindex of the element (defaulting to zIndex:1300). This zIndex is applied to the  element, NOT the MuiBackdrop-root div.

I've tried using the sx property, but it does not work to change the zIndex:1300 value.

[Customize the z-index of the react material ui select backdrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56831215/customize-the-z-index-of-the-react-material-ui-select-backdrop)

The above is a similar question to what I am trying to achieve, but that has different properties and as such the solution provided above does not apply to me.

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you're trying to achieve?